# AutoSubmit form problem within iFrame in Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, forms, submit

hey i have an a form named aform within an iframe. This form auto submitted in IE but in Firefox don't work. The iframe name is win
the code i use is on iframe onload="win.document.aform.submit();" 
but in firefox don't work. Is it possible to fix it
Any solutions ....
thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible to fix. First step is to accept the answers to the questions you have previously posted.

Comment: help me .....i will answer to the questions i posted...thank you Cybernate

Comment: Can you post the HTML code you are using?

Comment: Sure....
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>





</head>

<body >

<iframe  src="http://www.somedomain.com/form.html" width="700px" height="500px" name="win" id="win" onLoad="window.frames['win'].document.aform.submit();" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>

Comment: It doesn't work on me ......i tested it on firefox 4...in error console of firefox a get this error Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'

Comment: hmmm.. I was on Firefox 3.x...Let me check in 4

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ><iframe  src="http://www.somedomain.com/form.html" width="700px" height="500px" name="win" id="win" onLoad="window.frames['win'].document.aform.submit();" ></iframe></body>
```